# FastReport 5 gap between band and page footer

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have a simple test report with a Master data band and a page footer.  There appears to be a gap between the master band and the footer.  I set background colors on the band and footer to illustrate.

Screenshot:
[image]

I don't see any obvious way to get rid of this gap.   Setting the "Gap between bands" has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you read your question carefully you give the answer away, You are asking why is there a gap between your **Masterdata** band and a **Pagefooter**

Instead of using a Pagefooter just add a normal Footerband to the bottom of the masterdata band, because a Pagefooter as it suggests is a at the **Bottom** of the page where a **Footer** band is always at the bottom of its **MasterBand**

[image]

here is a Example of Footer vs Pagefooter

Comment: Thanks peter, but it had to be a footer.  I needed this footer to print at the end of every page, not just at the end of the band in case the band spanned pages.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add script code to manually set the curY

```
var CurY: extended;

procedure MasterData1OnAfterPrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  CurY := Engine.CurY;  
end;

procedure PageFooter1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
    Engine.CurY := CurY;  
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the master band will always be the same height (meaning the footer should always start at the same height), then you can set the page footer height to get rid of the gap. The page footer is measured from the top of the bottom margin.

For example, if you're using A4 size with a height of 297mm, the bottom margin is 15mm, and you want the footer to start 230mm from the top of the page, then you would want to set the footer height to be 297 - 15 - 230 = 52mm.